# How can I get my title and my bottom to show in Titanium?

Tags: titanium

```
var galWin = Ti.UI.createWindow({

    title: "Alejandro's Big Adventure",
    modal: true,
    backgroundColor: "828F99",
    layout: "horizontal"

});


var border = Ti.UI.createView({

    backgroundColor: "2585CC",
    height: 1,
    width: pWidth,
    top: 30

});


var bottomButton = Ti.UI.createView({

    backgroundColor: "828F99",
    height: "10%",
    width: pWidth,
    bottom: 0

});


var galContainer = Ti.UI.createScrollView({

    top: 0,
    width: pWidth,
    height: pHeight - border.height - border.top,
    backgroundColor: "2585CC",
    layout: "horizontal",
    contentWidth: pWidth,
    showVerticalScrollIndicator: true

});

for(var i = 0; i < myImages.length; i++){

    var view = Ti.UI.createView({

        borderRadius: 10,
        top: margin,
        left: margin,
        width: size,
        height: size

    });

    var img = Ti.UI.createImageView({

        image: "images/" + myImages[i],
        top: 0,
        width: view.width * 1.25,
        height: view.height * 2

    });

    view.add(img);
    galContainer.add(view);

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly: for the title if you want to get the title of the window
so you can get it with getTitle() method like this

```
galWin.getTitle()
```

secondly: for the bottom
if you want to get the bottom of the window here you can't do that because the window is the top element in you hierarchy and is the doc

```
Window's bottom position, in platform-specific units.
On Android, this property only works with lightweight windows. See "Android Heavyweight and Lightweight Windows" in the main description of Titanium.UI.Window for more information.
```

so you get the bottom of the element according to it's parent so here the window have no parent

but in general if you want to get the bottom of any element

you can use `getBottom()` but be aware that this method will return a number only if you provide a bottom property inside the element other than that you will get `Nan`

and if you want to get the bottom of an element after the layout drawn on the screen you can you `postlayout` event and using rect.y to get the top of the element and then you can add the element height and finally minus it from the window height and for that if you don't have the window height you can use displayCaps.contentHeight to get the screen height

sorry for Long hope it help